# "tscon 'SessionID' /dest:console" always shows "Session ID not found"

Tags: remote-desktop

I have a script that closes remote desktop connection and runs an application on a remote computer. It is helpful when the application requires a special access to your GPU.

To shut down the remote session the script uses:

tscon 'SessionID' /dest:console

The script is no longer working after I switched to Windows 10 -  tscon constantly shows "Session ID not found" error. I use "query session" to figure out my SessionID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Derp, just needed to run it with Administrative privileges (Right click -> run as administrator).